# android StartActivity crash

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, start-activity

i'm trying to go to my next activity , which is Nieuw_huis1
This is my code of the mainactivity where SetupNieuwHuis should redirect to the next page

```
    package com.jan.energyservice;

    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.PrintStream;

    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private EditText test;
private String data;
private String file = "mydata";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    test = (EditText) (findViewById(R.id.txtTest));

    setupNieuwHuis();
    slaietsop();
    tooniets();
}

    private void tooniets() {
        // 1 Reference
            Button Movebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLees);
            // 2 click listener to run code
            Movebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    read(test);
}});}

    private void slaietsop() {
    // 1 Reference
        Button Movebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTest);
        // 2 click listener to run code
        Movebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                save(test);
                                        }
            });
        }
    public void save(View view){
          data = test.getText().toString();
          try {
             FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(file,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
             new PrintStream(fOut).println("Naam van eerste ding");
             fOut.write(data.getBytes());
             fOut.close();
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"file saved",
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          } catch (Exception e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }
    public void read(View view){
          try{
             FileInputStream fin = openFileInput(file);
             int c;
             String temp="";
             while( (c = fin.read()) != -1){
                temp = temp + Character.toString((char)c);
             }
             test.setText(temp);
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"file read",
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          }catch(Exception e){
              }
          }

private void setupNieuwHuis() {
    // 1 Reference
    Button Movebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNieuwHuis);


    // 2 click listener to run code
    Movebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent =(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Nieuw_huis1.class));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

    }
```

But for some reason , when i start up my app, and i click on the button btnNieuwHuis , it crashes and gives me this error log

```
05-24 10:51:16.466: E/Trace(825): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-24 10:51:18.707: D/gralloc_goldfish(825): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
05-24 10:51:29.166: D/AndroidRuntime(825): Shutting down VM
05-24 10:51:29.166: W/dalvikvm(825): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
05-24 10:51:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(825): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-24 10:51:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(825): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.jan.energyservice/com.jan.energyservice.Nieuw_huis1}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
05-24 10:51:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1618)
05-24 10:51:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
05-24 10:51:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
05-24 10:51:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
05-24 10:51:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:840)
05-24 10:51:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
05-24 10:51:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
05-24 10:51:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at com.jan.energyservice.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:98)
05-24 10:51:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
05-24 10:51:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
05-24 10:51:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-24 10:51:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-24 10:51:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-24 10:51:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-24 10:51:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-24 10:51:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-24 10:51:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-24 10:51:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-24 10:51:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Also my activity is declared in AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.jan.energyservice"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".jan.energyservice.Nieuw_huis1"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_nieuw_huis1" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Nieuw_huis2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_nieuw_huis2" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Nieuw_huis3"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_nieuw_huis3" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Nieuw_huis4"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_nieuw_huis4" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

This is what i get after fixing the Manifest

```
05-25 11:26:24.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1120): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 11:26:24.184: E/AndroidRuntime    (1120):java.lang.RuntimeException:Unable to start activity ComponentInfo     {com.jan.energyservice/com.jan.energyservice.Nieuw_huis1}:     java.lang.NullPointerException
05-25 11:26:24.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
05-25 11:26:24.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-25 11:26:24.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-25 11:26:24.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-25 11:26:24.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-25 11:26:24.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-25 11:26:24.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-25 11:26:24.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 11:26:24.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-25 11:26:24.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-25 11:26:24.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-25 11:26:24.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-25 11:26:24.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1120): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-25 11:26:24.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at com.jan.energyservice.Nieuw_huis1.setupVolgendePagina(Nieuw_huis1.java:29)
05-25 11:26:24.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at com.jan.energyservice.Nieuw_huis1.onCreate(Nieuw_huis1.java:20)
05-25 11:26:24.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-25 11:26:24.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-25 11:26:24.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-25 11:26:24.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class . You haven't declared activity in manifest.

Comment: Normaly i did, or is i wrongly done?

Comment: just clean your project. it will work. or it may be mistake in package name!

Answer (score 0):

> have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Add your `Activity` to `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: i've just added it to my code above. It should be in order

Answer (score 0):

this portion is not correct, the package name isn't correct here, try this,

```
 <activity
    android:name="com.jan.energyservice.Nieuw_huis1"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_nieuw_huis1" >
</activity>
```

Comment: I've added the log above

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
   android:name=".Nieuw_huis1"
   android:label="@string/title_activity_nieuw_huis1" >
</activity>
```

Update your Menifest file with this.

Answer (score 0):

My first mistake , as was said by some, was a problem in my Manifest.
Second was a misdeclaration of a button in my second form (nieuw_huis1)

Thank you for all the help i received from you guys!